# Tensorflow Distributed Learning isn't working when using MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy in actual cluster

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed

I am just trying to follow example of [MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras) in tensorflow doc.
I succeed training in localhost, which has a single node.
However, I failed training in cluster, which has two nodes.
I have tried disabling firewall, but it didn't solve the problem.

Here is the main.py. (I run same code in node 1 and node 2, except the tf_config variable. I set node1's tf_config as `tf_config['task']['index']=0`, and node2's tf_config as `tf_config['task']['index']=1`)

[main.py](https://github.com/se-jeong-oh/DDLS/blob/main/multiworker.py)

Any helps Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "failed", what errors did it give? It would be helpful to see the error log

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't have an error code, but I think I can infer where the issue could be arising, since your code should work. I will test on my kubernetes once I get a chance (I have a node down atm).

- The most likely issue. You are using json.dumps() to set the environment variable. In many setting the you should be using:

  tf_config=json.loads(os.environ.get(TF_CONFIG) or '{}'),
  TASK_INDEX=tf_config['task']['index']

That should clear up any issues with expose ports and ip configurations.

-It sounds like the method you are using is in a notebook? Since you are not running the the same code for main.py. As in one main.py you set 1 and the other 0. Either way that is not what you are doing here. You are setting the index to 1 and 0 but you are not getting back only the index, you are getting back the full cluster spec with the index you set it to. If the environment variable is not set from your cluster, you will need to get back the TF_CONFIG that was set, and then use loads to set that as your tf_config, now you will be getting ONLY the replica index for that node.

- If you are using a notebook it needs to be connected to the cluster environment, otherwise you are setting a local environment variable to your machine, and not to containers on the cluster. Consider using Kubeflow, to manage this.
- You can either launch from the notebook after setting up your cluster
  configuration op, or build a TF_job spec as a YAML that defined the node specs, then launch the pods using that spec.
- Either way, the cluster needs to actually have that configuration, you should be able to load the environment in the cluster such that each node is ASSIGNED an index and you are getting that index from THAT nodes replica ID that you set when you launched the nodes and specified with a YAML or json dictionary. A locally set environment running within the local container means nothing to the actual cluster, if the replica-index:{num} on kubernetes does not match the environment variable on the container —That is assigned when the pod is launched.

-Try making a function that will return what the index of each worker is to test if it is set to the same replica-index on your kubernetes dashboard or from kubectl. Make sure to have the function print that out so you can see it in the pod logs. This will help with debugging.

-Look at the pod logs and see if the pods are connecting to the server, and are using whatever communication spec is compatible with your cluster:  grcp/etc. You are not setting a communication strategy, but it should be able to automatically find it for you in most cases (just check in case).

-If you are able to launch pods, make sure you are terminating them before trying again. Again kubeflow is going to make things so much easier for you once you get the hang of their python pipeline skd. You can launch functions as containers. You can build an op that clean up, by terminating old pods.

-You should consider having your main.py and any other supporting modules loaded on an image in a repository, such as dockerhub, so that the containers can load the image. With Multiworker Strategy, each machine needs to have the same data for it to be sharded properly. Again check your pod logs to see if it cannot shard the data.

-Are you running on a local machine with different GPUs? If so you should be using Mirrored Strategy NOT multiworker.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a lot of things that could be going wrong that are related to your configuration, what are you running on? Are you using minikube, or are you splitting your CPU cores? I can suggest general improvements that could help with your code to handle more communication options. Also you don't seem to have data distribution options. The only thing you place within the scope of the strategy context manager is the model definition and compile. It also looks like those two nodes are sharing the same port. It's better to set TF_config as an environment variable that is passed into

'tf_config = json.loads(os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG') or '{}')'

Here is an example of set-ups I have used in the past it worked both running on multiple CPU threads through mini-kube, and on a Kubernetes framework.

Model replaced with a simple mnist model.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import argparse
import json
import os

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models


def make_datasets_unbatched():
  BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

  # Scaling MNIST data from (0, 255] to (0., 1.]
  def scale(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /= 255
    return image, label

  datasets, _ = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

  return datasets['train'].map(scale).cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)


def build_and_compile_cnn_model():
  model = models.Sequential()
  model.add(
      layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

  model.summary()

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model


def decay(epoch):
  if epoch < 3: #pylint: disable=no-else-return
    return 1e-3
  if 3 <= epoch < 7:
    return 1e-4
  return 1e-5


def main(args):

  # MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy creates copies of all variables in the model's
  # layers on each device across all workers
  # if your GPUs don't support NCCL, replace "communication" with another
  strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy(
      communication=tf.distribute.experimental.CollectiveCommunication.NCCL)

  BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 64
  BATCH_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

  with strategy.scope():
    ds_train = make_datasets_unbatched().batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
    options = tf.data.Options()
    options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = \
        tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
    ds_train = ds_train.with_options(options)
    # Model building/compiling need to be within `strategy.scope()`.
    multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model()

  # Define the checkpoint directory to store the checkpoints
  checkpoint_dir = args.checkpoint_dir

  # Name of the checkpoint files
  checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

  # Function for decaying the learning rate.
  # You can define any decay function you need.
  # Callback for printing the LR at the end of each epoch.
  class PrintLR(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): #pylint: disable=no-self-use
      print('\nLearning rate for epoch {} is {}'.format(
        epoch + 1, multi_worker_model.optimizer.lr.numpy()))

  callbacks = [
      tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs'),
      tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
                                         save_weights_only=True),
      tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(decay),
      PrintLR()
  ]

  # Keras' `model.fit()` trains the model with specified number of epochs and
  # number of steps per epoch. Note that the numbers here are for demonstration
  # purposes only and may not sufficiently produce a model with good quality.
  multi_worker_model.fit(ds_train,
                         epochs=10,
                         steps_per_epoch=70,
                         callbacks=callbacks)

  # Saving a model
  # Let `is_chief` be a utility function that inspects the cluster spec and
  # current task type and returns True if the worker is the chief and False
  # otherwise.
  def is_chief():
    return TASK_INDEX == 0

  if is_chief():
    model_path = args.saved_model_dir

  else:
    # Save to a path that is unique across workers.
    model_path = args.saved_model_dir + '/worker_tmp_' + str(TASK_INDEX)

  multi_worker_model.save(model_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['NCCL_DEBUG'] = 'INFO'

  tfds.disable_progress_bar()

  # to decide if a worker is chief, get TASK_INDEX in Cluster info
  tf_config = json.loads(os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG') or '{}')
  TASK_INDEX = tf_config['task']['index']

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--saved_model_dir',
                      type=str,
                      required=True,
                      help='Tensorflow export directory.')

  parser.add_argument('--checkpoint_dir',
                      type=str,
                      required=True,
                      help='Tensorflow checkpoint directory.')

  parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
  main(parsed_args)
```

Comment: I just realized I answered this question a long time ago